# questions on a property of ARCH model

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, time-series

When reading the book of `Analysis of Financial Time Series`, I have a question on the ARCH model, defined as follows

[image]

Regarding this model, the author also states that.

[image]

I do not understand why does the equation marked with yellow color is satisfied.

Comment: I don't immediately follow what calculations the author used here, however the fourth central moment of the $N(0,\sigma^2)$ distribution is commonly known to be $3\sigma^4$. See section 2.2 of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Moments.

Comment: See [Isserlis' Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isserlis%27_theorem) for more details.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$E(a_t^4|F_{t-1}) = E(\sigma_t^4\epsilon_t^4|F_{t-1}) = E(\epsilon_t^4|F_{t-1}) * E[(\sigma_t^2)^2|F_{t-1}] = 3(\alpha_0 + \alpha_1a_{t-1}^2)^2 $

I suggest reading up on the law of iterated expectations.

Ninja edit to your specific question is we know $E(\epsilon_t^4|F_{t-1})$ = 3